# Gmail API - only allow authorised users to connect

Tags: php, google-api

Right now I am programming a website that allows users to log-in through a Google API and PHP. I need to fix my code to allow only one user to be able to log-in and reject any others. What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean for a google account only one user should be connected at once ? Or you mean only one user connected at once for the whole system ?

Comment: Hi, I mean that only one google account can be authenticated, not any other.

Comment: I used that google-api client once. And you can use your session storage to check if there is a valid active session with an ID that you manually generate. That ID will just be the google User ID